# « Être » dans une citation tirée de Fernand Braudel

Tags: grammaire, sens

Phrase tirée par [Identité de la France, Fernand Braudel](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7-lnAAAAMAAJ&q=Identit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20France,%20Fernand%20Braudel%20toute%20nation%20est%20divis%C3%A9e&dq=Identit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20France,%20Fernand%20Braudel%20toute%20nation%20est%20divis%C3%A9e&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyg7aNy_HbAhUFKFAKHRtVAzgQ6AEIKDAA) :

> Toute nation est divisée, vit de l'*être*.

Que signifie *être* ici et quelle est sa classe grammaticale ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ce qui concerne le sens, il faut comprendre '*Toute nation vit d'être divisée*',
On pourrait reformuler de façon certes moins élégante mais plus compréhensible : '*Toute nation **a** des divisions et vit d'**avoir** ces divisions*'.
Ou mieux '*Toute nation est divisée et vit (existe, prospère) grâce à ces divisions*'

Answer (score 2):

`être` est le noyau du groupe infinitif `l'être` (qui est COI de `vit`).

Mini-remarques :

- `l'` est attribut du sujet de `être` et représente `divisée`.
- ce n'est pas une proposition infinitive, car `l'être` n'a pas de sujet propre (ici c'est implicitement `Toute nation`).
- je ne tiens pas compte de `est divisée` car la construction `Toute nation est divisée, vit de l'être.` n'est pas canonique, elle est disloquée (`vit de l'être` vient replacer `est divisée`). Stylistiquement, on dirait une [épanorthose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89panorthose).

Je ne sais pas si on peut caractériser plus précisément la fonction de `être`.